# (getTime() - 5 * 3600 * 1000) takes 3 hours back and not 5

Tags: javascript, date, google-ads-script

I'm trying to query stats for the hour which as the time 5 hours ago.

When I run this code, I see in the logs that the local time is 6 so I expect `pastHour` to be 1, but it says 3.

Why?

[image]

```
var HOURS_BACK = 5;

function main() {

  var past = new Date(new Date().getTime() - HOURS_BACK * 3600 * 1000);
  var pastHour = past.getHours();
  var pastDateStr = getDateStringInTimeZone(past, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  query = "SELECT customer.id, metrics.impressions, segments.hour FROM customer WHERE metrics.impressions = 0 AND segments.hour = " + pastHour + " AND segments.date = '" + pastDateStr + "'";
  Logger.log("query " + query);
  }
```

Comment: The culprit probably is your `getDateStringInTimeZone()` function. Think about where in the world you are when you test your code.

Comment: @Pointy `pastHour` should still be correct then, though.

Comment: well, `pastHour` depents on the current time. If it's currenlty 2022-01-20T08:00:00 then `currentTime - 5 hours` will be `2022-01-20T03:00:00` and `getHours` wil return `3`. I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Right, the normal Date APIs assume *local* time, while the timestamp-based constructor involves UTC time (because all timestamps are UTC).

Comment: When I run this code, I see in the logs that the local time is 6 so I expect `pastHour` to be 1, but it says 3.

Comment: Again, what is your local time zone? `.getHours()` returns your **local** hour-of-day, not the UTC hour-of-day.

Comment: Just print `past.getHours()` and `new Date().getHours()` and you'll see they differ by 5. The problem is that `getDateStringInTimeZone` is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the log showed the local hour of day

Comment: @Pointy consider making it an answer. If you feel uneasy about accumulating rep with it consider a community wiki. I think this is googleable/common enough :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sure, though this is essentially a duplicate of a problem that plays out over and over again, forever :)

Comment: @pointy—that the constructor takes a UTC time value is irrelevant to the issue. The OP is directly manipulating the time value, that change should be reflected in the local time too and only ever differ if it causes an offset change (e.g. crosses a daylight saving boundary), in which case the difference should not be more than 1 hour.

Comment: The local time is 6pm, which is 18 hours. So 18 - 5 is 13. That you're seeing 3 can't be explained by the information presented. Note that subtracting 1.8e7 milliseconds (5 hrs) from the time value **should** reduce both the UTC and local times by 5 hours. The only exception is where the 5 hours moves over a DST boundary, so the local time might appear to change between 4 to 6 hours, but that's extremely unlikely to have occurred between 1 and 6 pm (13 to 18 hours) local.

Comment: Note also that you need to look beyond the hours. 2 am minus 5 hours is 21 hours or 9 pm the previous day, so you need to look at both the date and time.

Comment: @RobG on the contrary, this way of reduction (as oppose to using "setHour()") handles the date change. I've tested this : https://snipboard.io/Ld3GYK.jpg

Comment: @EladBenda— *setHours* isn't used anywhere in the posted code. The query string contains "*…AND segments.hour = " + pastHour + " AND segments.date = '"…*" so it's looking at hour and date, as commented. Can you post something that replicates the issue described in the OP?

Comment: @RobG Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. pastDateStr would be correct, what do you mean by `The only exception is where the 5 hours moves over a DST boundary...`

Comment: The code for *getDateStringInTimeZone* is not included, nor is an explanation of what it does, so it's not clear that *pastDateStr* returns the same date that *pastHour* is based on. Where subtracting 5 hours from the underlying UTC time value moves over a DST boundary, the local (i.e. host specific) value returned by *getHours* may be ±1 hour (or ±30 minutes in some places).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit* — I'll leave the content below, but I now think that the mystery of the OP is not explainable by what's posted in the question.

---

It's important to keep in mind how Date values work. Internally, a Date is *always* a UTC-relative timestamp. That is, if (hypothetically) you and somebody across the world from you *simultaneously* called `new Date().getTime()`, you'd both get the same timestamp. (Obviously not really possible, but imagine you live in a cartoon world.)

However, the Date APIs like `.getHours()` work in your *local* time. The difference between local time and universal time causes lots of people confusion all the time, and things only get worse when your date/time values are subsequently involved in database operations, where the same problems may crop up once again.

Comment: This doesn't expalin anything about why the OP sees an incorrect value. There is nothing in the OP to suggest why the wrong value is being presented (3 instead of 13). It is not because the OP is adjusting the time value directly then reading local hours, since the timestamp being used for comparison is also local. It also can't be due to *getDateStringInTimeZone* since that function plays no part in setting the value of *pastHour*.

Comment: @RobG since this is a community wiki answer you are welcome to just go ahead and incorporate your feedback into the answer directly..

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum—I'd do that but there isn't enough information in the OP to determine why the issue occurs, so an answer isn't possible, hence my vote to close.

Comment: @RobG I understand your sentiment and indeed it's probably not a great way to ask a question but I suspect it's a fairly common one and one people are likely to google

Comment: Hey gang, I admit that upon looking at this again, the whole thing is hard to understand, and certainly hard to reproduce.